# What is the correct way of selecting drop down text in jQuery starting from a div?

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically grabbing a selected drop down option's text from an array of divs. When I do this:

```
$("#divID").children("select").eq(0).find('option:selected').text();
```

Everything works fine. However, when I do this:

```
$("#divID").children("select option:selected").eq(0).text();
```

It does not grab the text as expected. I was wondering what I am doing wrong with the latter approach to getting the text. Thanks.

[JSFiddle - First Approach (Works)](http://jsfiddle.net/q7RSj/)

[JSFiddle - Second Approach (Doesn't Work)](http://jsfiddle.net/nzhaD/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with what you are doing is your use of `children`.

If you were to change `children` to `find` then it works perfectly. The reason is that `children` only finds elements that are direct children of the set being acted on. So it will only return things that are direct children of `#divID`. As you can see the `option` elements are not direct children so they can't be returned.

```
$("#divID").find("select option:selected").eq(0).text();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nzhaD/5/

Of course there are some subtle differences between the two of these. Cosnider this HTML:

```
<div id="divLocation">
    <div>            
        <select id="1"/>
    </div>
    <select id="2"/>
</div>
```

I've cut the options out but your original selector will get id #2 (since it is the only select that is a child of `#divLocation` whereas mine would get the first selected option which will be presumably in id #1.

So the moral of the story is do whichever selector does what you actually want it to. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was assuming that the select elements' options were a part of the select element itself and not children of the select element. This makes perfect sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would have done this one:

```
    value = $("#divLocation select option:selected").text();
```

I don't know exactly which approch is the "correct one". I think mine is simple to understand. So go for the one that you think is easy to read. If performance is necessary use just pure javascript and let the select have an ID.

```
document.getElementById("divLocationSelect").value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzhaD/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("#divID").find("select option:selected").eq(0).text();
```

The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

See [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)